# Symfony 2: Sonata sortable

Tags: php, symfony, sonata-admin, symfony-sonata

I have in my entity:

```
/**
 * @ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity="Sancho\UserBundle\Entity\followers", mappedBy="followers")
 */
private $followers;
```

In Sonata i want to get the number of $followers[]. I create in my entity:

```
public function getFollow()
{
      return count($this->followers);
}
```

In UserAdmin i have:

```
protected function configureListFields(ListMapper $listMapper)
{
    $listMapper
        ->add('id')
            ->add('follow', null, array('sortable'=>true));
}
```

I have the number of $follow[] but i can't sort the field. When i sort i have the error:

```
PHP Catchable fatal error:  Argument 1 passed to Sonata\\DoctrineORMAdminBundle\\Datagrid\\ProxyQuery::entityJoin() must be of the type array, null given, called in /home/sancho/work/Web/vendor/sonata-project/doctrine-orm-admin-bundle/Datagrid/ProxyQuery.php on line 140 and defined in /home/sancho/work/Web/vendor/sonata-project/doctrine-orm-admin-bundle/Datagrid/ProxyQuery.php on line 245
```

Comment: you can implement this solution: [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36153381/sort-list-view-in-sonata-admin-by-related-entity-fields](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36153381/sort-list-view-in-sonata-admin-by-related-entity-fields)

Answer (score 1):

Your looking in the wrong direction... **Sortable** in sonata is used to define a field that will hold a position number so you can indeed order the things but based on indexes it writes for itself, so it requires a field in the database thats why you get that error. What you need to do is override the **createQuery** method in the admin class with ordering functionality. Take a look [here](http://sonata-project.org/bundles/admin/master/doc/reference/action_list.html) how to do that.

Comment: Do you have an example with a OneToMany link ? I have 2 entities (User and Follow). For the moment i use getFollow() {return count($this->followers;}. How can i sort my field by the number of "follow" with queryBuilder ?

Comment: he suggests doing a group by. but that does not work. still looking for a solution

Comment: I am getting crazy with this issue, did anyone find a solution ?

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if this applies to your situation. But I believe the problem may be how you access the field.

```
->add('follow', null, array('sortable'=>true));
```

You should use

```
->add('followers.follow');
```

I had a relation between a 'store' and 'product' and I used `ManyToOne`relations and from the relation table I had `->addIdentifier('store')` which apparently uses __toString method and therefore can't be sorted. However when I associate `->addIdentifier('store.name')` it is the `name` field which can be sorted.